# Preserving Container Directory Contents with Docker Volume Sync

Tags: bash, docker, synchronization, containers, volumes

I'm encountering a challenge in a Docker setup where I aim to synchronize files between a host and a container, but face the unintended deletion of pre-setup content in the container's `/app` directory. This happens when an initially empty host volume is mounted to the container.

Here's the relevant content of my Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM python:3.10

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Installations and setup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git rsync
RUN pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv
# [Additional setup commands...]

# Create directories for applications
RUN mkdir llmware_dir aider_chat_dir codeqai_dir llmlingua_dir autogen_dir
# [Further configurations and environment setups...]

# Copy and set permissions for the startup script
COPY startup.sh ./
RUN chmod +x startup.sh

# Run the startup script
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

The startup script (`startup.sh`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Sync files from the mounted volume to /app
rsync -a /host_volume/ /app/

# Original CMD command
tail -f /dev/null
```

And the container is run with:

```bash
docker run -it --name llm_container -e OPENAI_API_KEY=%OPENAI_API_KEY% -v llm_volume:/host_volume llm_img
```

How can I ensure the `/app` directory contents are preserved while syncing only new or changed files from `host_volume`?

Comment: Can your application code reference the user data in the container `/host_volume` directory, without necessarily moving a copy of it into `/app`?  If a file changes in the image, how can you tell if what's seen when the new container starts is intentionally modified by the user?

Comment: Yes, it can reference user data in the `/host_volume` directory. I can check by going interactive mode with `bash` and checking the contents of the files. The problem is the files are overwritten when the  `/host_volume`  directory is empty in the host machine so it deletes all the files downloaded in the containers directory,

Comment: `/host_volume` should normally be an empty directory in the image in this setup.

Comment: Yes it is empty I believe that the `startup script` did not fully work